# Do I have to sort dates chronologically to use pandas.DataFrame.ewm?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I need to calculate `EMA` for a set of data from csv file where dates are in `descending order`.

When I apply `pandas.DataFrame.ewm` I get EMA for the latest (by date) equal to the value. This is because `ewm` starts observation from top to bottom in `DataFrame`.

So far, I could not find option to make it reverse for `ewm`. So I guess, I will have to reverse all my dataset.

Maybe somebody knows how to make `ewm` start from bottom values?
Or is it recommended to always use `datetimeindex` sorted chronologically? From oldest values on top to newest on the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From pandas' documentation:

> Times corresponding to the observations. Must be monotonically increasing and datetime64[ns] dtype.

I guess, datetimeindex must be chronological..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reset your index temporarily.

```
df.index.name = 'date' # IF YOU HAVEN'T SET A NAME YET
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
# PERFORM EWM OPERATIONS
```

Then set it back to the original `DateTimeIndex`

```
df = df.set_index('date')
```

Comment: On a related note: it is good practice to have a monotonically increasing index. It optimizes lookup operations in `pd.Series` - and by extension - `pd.DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

I proposed a similar question here: [rolling window in pandas dataframe in reverse date order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73619682/rolling-window-in-pandas-dataframe-in-reverse-date-order/73619718?noredirect=1#comment130004023_73619718)

where the concluding options are:

- double reverse
- sorting

The double reverse is preferred because sorting is "expensive" (although I have not compared both myself).