# rolling window in pandas dataframe in reverse date order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that i apply a `rolling()` window. However the dates are sorted newest to oldest, so the missing part (the window width) is at the top.

To avoid this i `reverse sort by dates` and then apply the `rolling()` method. However, this  seems to be inefficient, so was wondering **if there is a way to apply rolling from the bottom upwards?**

Example dataframe:

```
    Symbol       Date     Open     High      Low    Close
0  UKX:IND 2022-09-01  7284.15  7284.15  7131.69  7148.50
1  UKX:IND 2022-08-31  7361.63  7378.44  7263.62  7284.15
2  UKX:IND 2022-08-30  7427.31  7486.40  7351.12  7361.63
3  UKX:IND 2022-08-26  7479.74  7530.65  7422.02  7427.31
4  UKX:IND 2022-08-25  7471.51  7535.70  7469.17  7479.74
5  UKX:IND 2022-08-24  7488.11  7488.12  7410.40  7471.51
6  UKX:IND 2022-08-23  7533.79  7533.79  7467.56  7488.11
7  UKX:IND 2022-08-22  7550.37  7550.41  7491.26  7533.79
8  UKX:IND 2022-08-19  7541.85  7578.85  7513.26  7550.37
9  UKX:IND 2022-08-18  7515.75  7541.89  7493.66  7541.85
```

This is the relevant part of the code:

```py
df = df.sort_values(by='Date')   # <--  do a reverse sort
df['ma'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=5).mean()
df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)   # <-- sort back again
```

What i have tried ?

- i try things like including a negative number: `rolling(window=-5)`
- i try searching the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

So far, my only solution is to reverse the dataframe by date (and then reverse it back).

Comment: the double reverse is a good solution (indexing is relatively fast, no need to sort)

Comment: @mozway,  really ?  it just feels like i am have missed something...  if the dataframe was large, then is a `double reverse` optimal ?

Comment: double reverse yes, double sort no, (see my answer) ;)

Comment: so you are saying that `double reverse` is better than a `sort` ?

Comment: sorting is more expensive yes

Comment: but note that it is a double reverse (2 operations) vs a single sort (1 operation).

Comment: sorting is not the same complexity though: O(n*logn) vs O(n), and reversing is quite fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to sort twice, use indexing to temporarily reverse, which should be faster:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
df['ma'] = df['Close'][::-1].rolling(window=5).mean()[::-1]
print(df)
```

Or even:

```
df['ma'] = df['Close'][::-1].rolling(window=5).mean()
```

as pandas aligns the indices before assignement

output:

```
    Symbol        Date     Open     High      Low    Close        ma
0  UKX:IND  2022-09-01  7284.15  7284.15  7131.69  7148.50  7340.266
1  UKX:IND  2022-08-31  7361.63  7378.44  7263.62  7284.15  7404.868
2  UKX:IND  2022-08-30  7427.31  7486.40  7351.12  7361.63  7445.660
3  UKX:IND  2022-08-26  7479.74  7530.65  7422.02  7427.31  7480.092
4  UKX:IND  2022-08-25  7471.51  7535.70  7469.17  7479.74  7504.704
5  UKX:IND  2022-08-24  7488.11  7488.12  7410.40  7471.51  7517.126
6  UKX:IND  2022-08-23  7533.79  7533.79  7467.56  7488.11       NaN
7  UKX:IND  2022-08-22  7550.37  7550.41  7491.26  7533.79       NaN
8  UKX:IND  2022-08-19  7541.85  7578.85  7513.26  7550.37       NaN
9  UKX:IND  2022-08-18  7515.75  7541.89  7493.66  7541.85       NaN
```

Comment: To use the `rolling` function, doesn't the index have to be a `datetime` like index?

Comment: @KarthikS If you want to roll on a time window, it's preferable. Although you can also provide the column with `on='Date'`. In this case, OP probably wanted to use a fixed window.